# Pyre Check: verification error - `eval` is not part of the environment, no module `eval` in search path

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyre-check, pysa

I'm trying to set up Pyre Check Pysa just as described in the official tutorial: https://github.com/facebook/pyre-check/tree/main/documentation/pysa_tutorial/exercise2

When running `pyre analyze` I get the following errors:

```
ƛ Found 2 model verification errors! 
sources_sinks.pysa:5:0 `eval` is not part of the environment, no module `eval` in search path.
sources_sinks.pysa:7:0 `subprocess.getoutput` is not part of the environment, no module `subprocess` in search path.
```

I already extended my `.pyre_configuration:

```
{
  "source_directories": [
    "."
  ],
  "taint_models_path": [
    "."
  ],
  "search_path": [
    "../../../stubs/",
    "~/.venvs/pysa/lib/python3.10/site-packages/",
    "~/.venvs/pysa/lib/pyre_check"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    ".*/integration_test/.*"
  ]
}
```

but it doesn't help. What can I do to get pysa running? Does the tutorial work for you?

I tried it on native Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS as well as WLS Ubuntu-20.04.

Answer (score 0):

using the following commands should solve the issue:

```
python3 -m venv tutorial
```

and

```
source tutorial/bin/activate
```

Comment: That's just using an virtual environment? How should that solve my problem? It sadly does not.
The problem is that pyre thinks that "`eval` is not part of the environment"